# How many different sums of parts of a vector

Tags: co.combinatorics

I hope this question isn't too basic for MO.  I also asked it on [math.se previously](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1373679/how-many-different-sums-of-parts-of-a-vector).  This mathematical puzzle was given to me by a friend a while ago and I can't work out how to solve it. Does anyone have any ideas?

For a given vector $v \in \{-1,1\}^n$ we consider the following $n$ sums. $$S_j=\sum_{i=0}^j v_i - \sum_{i=j+1}^{n-1} v_i \text{ for } 0 \leq j \leq n-1.$$

For example if $v = (-1,1,1)$ then $S=(-3,-1,1).$

Now let $T_j = 1$ if $S_j>0$ and $0$ otherwise. So for our example vector $v$ we have that $T=(0,0,1)$

Considered over all $2^n$ possible vectors $v$, the question is how many different possible vectors $T$ are there?

I think if $n=2$ the answer is $3$, if $n=3$ the answer is $8$, if $n=4$ the answer is $11$, if $n=5$, the answer is $22$ and if $n=6$ the answer is $31$.  I have looked on OEIS with no luck.

Comment: The sequence has the following initial terms (courtesy of Python):
2,3,8,11,22,31,58,83,152,219,398,575,1042,1507,2728,3947,7142,10335,18698,27059.

Based on these terms, I conjecture the generating function

$\frac{x^6+2x^5+x^4-3x^2-2x}{(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+x-1)(x^2-x-1)}$.

This would imply an exponential growth rate equal to that of the Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: If the sequence is $a_i$ (with $a_1=2$) and $f_i$ is the $i$th Fibonacci number (with $f_1=f_2=1$), then it seems $|a_i - f_{i+3}|$ is the sequence: [A109522](http://oeis.org/A109522)

Comment: This would imply (with notation from above) that your sequence is $a_i = f_{i+3} + (-1)^{(i-3)}f_{i-3} + \frac{(-1)^{(i-3)}-1}{2}$. Maybe this will help find a proof.

Comment: @JayPantone Thank you very much! I am very impressed you got an exact formula so quickly.  How did you guess $|a_i - f_{i+3}|$?

Comment: A proof has been posted on Math.SE.